# How to auto-expand all relations having a given type in Spring Data REST?

Tags: spring-data-rest

My use case is localization: many entities have multilingual properties which are are mapped as relationships to a MultilingualString class. Is there any way I can configure my Spring Data REST API so that it automatically expands these relationships in every entity?

Having Projections perform the work could be an option, but creating separate projections for every entity which has multilingual properties seems unnecessarily cumbersome. Is there a better option?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to access these `MultilingualString` entities directly?

If not, then simply do NOT expose that repository.
If no repository endpoint for those entities, all of them will be automatically inserted to their parent objects.

```
@RepositoryRestResource(exported = false)
public interface MultilingualStringRepository extends AclJpaRepository<MultilingualString, {whatever}>
```